# How can I remove leading spaces/tabs up to a point with pasted code?

Tags: javascript

I'm toying around with handling pasted code in a textarea and wanted to left trim what is pasted up to the first non-spacing character. I want to take the following code:

```
    if (foo)
    {
        console.log(bar);
    }
```

And present it like so:

```
if (foo)
{
    console.log(bar);
}
```

I've written code that breaks the text up so that I have each line in an array, then I iterate through that array, store the least amount of spaces in a variable, then iterate through the array again, using substr() to return the string after X characters. If any line has no leading space or tab, then no trimming should occur. What I have works (haven't added support for tabs yet), but I believe there is a better way to do this. I've got a working sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghYAA/).

So... anyone know how I can accomplish this more efficiently?

Comment: Basically you just coded the entire logic for "trim what is pasted up to the first non-spacing character". I doubt there is some other way to get this done, different from counting the empty area width line-by-line and then doing actual trimming. Of course, there are some ways to make your code a bit more readable/maintanable, but nothing really more efficient.

Comment: It seems this problem gets more complex when dealing with a string that combines tabs and spaces. I'm guessing one would just have to settle on a tab being a fixed number of spaces if they didn't want to get into complex heuristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This iterates through an array consisting of the spaces at the begning of each line. The iteration is done using jQuery's [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), but it could be done in two lines pretty easily with a loop if you prefer. It uses Math.min to find the smallest number of spaces in that array. Then it just replaces exactly that may spaces from the beginning of every line with the empty string:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var code = $('#code').val();

    var space_count = Math.min.apply(null, $.map(code.match(/^\s+/gm), function(x){ return x.length; }));
    var new_code = code.replace(RegExp('^\\s{' + space_count + '}', 'gm'), '');

    $('pre:first').text(code);
    $('pre:last').text(new_code);
});​
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghYAA/2/)

[**And another for fun**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghYAA/3/)

As for tabs, you'll have to make a decision on how many spaces you consider a tab to be. Probably 4 or 5 would be a good choice. Then you can replace all tabs at the start of every line with that many spaces before reusing the same logic for spaces.

Comment: Very nice. This is close to what I'm looking for. `\n\n` ends up being replaced with `\n\s`, so `}\n\nfunction ()` ends up becoming `}\n\sfunction ()`. As for tabs, I'm content replacing them with four spaces for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of strings, then sorting them will put those starting with a space at the start (since space has the lowest ASCII code of any printed character). Therefore the last member of the array will have the equal least number of leading spaces (which might be zero).

So the number of leading characters to trim is given by:

```
function spacesToTrim(s) {
  s = s.split('\n').sort();
  var n = s[s.length - 1].match(/^\s*/);
  return n? n[0].length : 0;
}
```

And since array operations like `split` and `sort` are very fast, it should be very much faster than any interative method, particularly one that iterates over the array twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to match the leading whitespace from the beginning of the string and if found then replace all occurrences of `/(^|$)[matched whitespace]/g` with the first matching group:

```javascript
function shiftLeft(s) {
  var m = s.match(/(\s+)/);
  return (m) ? s.replace(new RegExp('(^|\n)' + m[1], 'g'), '$1') : s;
}
var s = shiftLeft('  def foo()\n    puts "ok"\n  end\n');
s; // => 'def foo()\n  puts "ok"\nend\n'
```

Comment: I was hoping to achieve the trim regardless of where the fewest spacing characters occurred, be it on the first line, last line or somewhere in the middle. In those situations, the spaces would remain if there are fewer than the first line.

Comment: @Mathachew: yes, I'm sure such a solution is possible.  Try matching on `/(?:^|\n)(\s+)/g`, finding the longest matching string, and using that as the "[matched whitespace]" to remove.